# Security - How to secure your .json files in a shared hosting?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, security

I want to store some data in .json files in a directory called `json`.

```
index.php
  dir1/
  dir2/
  json/
    data1.json
    data2.json
    and so on...
```

the json data can be as simple as,

```
{
    "John": {
        "status":"Wait"
    },
    "Jennifer": {
        "status":"Active"
    },
    "James": {
        "status":"Active",
        "age":56,
        "count":10,
        "progress":0.0029857,
        "bad":0
    }
}
```

my concerns are  -

1. how secured it is to keep the data in this way?
2. can these json data files be hacked (deleted or modified) by hackers? (it is fine to be viewed by everyone)

If this way is not safe, can MongoDB be a solution? is it safe then for data to keep in MongoDB?

Comment: What do you mean by "secured" ... can't be read by world+dog or can't be modified by world+dog?

Answer (score 1):

> how secured it is to keep the data in this way?

As secure as keeping it in any other static file stored under the web root.

> can these json data files be hacked (deleted or modified) by hackers?

Only as much as any static file on the server could be.

> if it is not safe, can MongoDB be a solution? is it safe then for data to keep in MongoDB?

MongoDB provides mechanisms for editing the data inside it, so you have to take more care with how you configure permissions on it. By adding the complexity of MongoDB, the chances of something going wrong and the data being editable from outside your server go up.

Answer (score 1):

> how secured it is to keep the data in this way?

The data is accessible via the web so anybody can view it.

> can these json data files be hacked (deleted or modified) by hackers?

Everything can be hacked. While the files aren't easily editable via the web, as long as you don't allow DAV access, someone could hack into the server. Moving them to MongoDB isn't a hacker-proof solution either, of course. In fact, you moving the data to a web-accesible MongoDB just provides another attack vector.

Answer (score 1):

In a dedicated environment you would have some luck in disallowing the file, stopping directory reads and getting, at least some way, to securing these files. Afterall it is a lot like a firewall, they can't hack it if you don't give them a foothold, it isn't some kind of magical barrier that can be brought down if you tap the keys enough times.

However, in a shared enviroment you do not have control over such things. You in fact have 0 access to the security features of your server so...my bet is that these files are easily accessible and "hackable" by outsiders.

> If this way is not safe, can MongoDB be a solution?

No because MongoDB would never happily run on a shared envionment. Just quit shared if you want to be a real web developer and get a vmed/docked instance from Heroku or AWS or Rackspace. They are dirt cheap.

Comment: `Heroku or AWS or Rackspace` are cloud hosting, arent they? I don't understand how cloud hosting works really, especially comes to the price for it. for instance, I can I know how much resources I need for a website?

Comment: @tealou Well shared hostig gives you a standard set of about 130MB for a PHP site I believe, whereas the smallest cloud sever will normally give about 1GB, and you can scale it up in realtime, that is the power of cloud servers

Comment: scale-ability - that is one of the concept in cloud hosting that I don't understand. what are things that need to be scaled?

Comment: @tealou sorry I meant memory, they would also limit your CPU to a very small amount making your site impossible to run more than what your own personal computer could.

Comment: @tealou resources that would need to be scaled would be servers. So you would have 5 app severs each taking requests fed to them by a load balancer. Dynamically you can just add a new app sev e to take the strain of another like 10,000 hit seamlessly beind the works. Also some cloud servers allow you to actually rebuild the server while it is accessed but I never trust that mechanism

Comment: Thanks Sammaye for trying to explain this. I think I'm too stupid to understand cloud hosting! It seems to me that you can never know how much `memory (CPU)` you need for your website and it is charged by hours (this is another confusion to me) and that it seems to come with a hidden cost! Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the MIME map for json from the Server configuration.
in IIS for e.g, add

```
 <staticContent><remove fileExtension=".json" /></staticContent>
```